# PHP mySQL best practices regarding lookups

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

My question:
I have a mysql database that consists of something like a fact table (although not every field is a lookup) and a variety of other tables. When I want to display data from that "fact" table, is it necessary to run a query to each individual lookup *or* is there a way to make a temporary table that has already done the "looking up"?

Example:
Table structure -

- unique_id(auto increment int),
- model(int, lookup to table #2),
- type(int, lookup from table #2 to table #3)
- employee(int, lookup to table #4)
- notes(text)
- cost(float)
- hours(float)
  -

So for instance when I want to make a php page to enter this data it seems like a lot more "work" than it needs to be:

- unique_id (not shown as a data entry field, increments automatically 
  on submit)
- model (drop down box. population requires query to table #2 where status = X)
- type (read-only text box shows type of model. Requires query to table #3 based on column from table #2)
- employee (drop down box. population requires query to table #4 where employee_status = "Active")
- notes (text box, user inputs related notes to submission)
- cost (texts box, user enters costs related to submission)
- hours (text box, user enters hours related to submission)

Just to get a simple form populated with valid data requires what seems to me like *A LOT* of queries/lookups.

Is this the best way? Is there a better way?

Aside: I have control over the data structure, so if the problem is the database design, then those suggestions would be helpful as well.

Comment: seems like drop down boxes are being replaced by text fields that autocomplete entered data for you, like what you see on FB and google.

Comment: That's a good point Frank. I could change those drop boxes to auto-complete txt boxes. I've used those in the past for a few other things. However, that still doesn't solve the lookup issues. Even when I autocomplete, I'll still have to lookup the next associated value to populate the "read only" fields. Unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: Also, using the text box approack, you would be making ajax calls to seperate php scripts. Thinking of it, it's something you might do, even with drop down lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimension tables typically don't change very often, at least relative to the number of inserts to the fact table.  Dimension tables are also individually much smaller than the fact table.  This makes dimension tables good candidates for caching.

What some people do to good effect is to render the partial HTML output for the form, with all the data populated as dropdowns, radiobuttons, etc.  Then store that partial HTML under a memcached key so you don't have to do any of the database queries or the HTML render for most PHP requests -- you just fetch the pre-populated HTML fragment out of memcached and echo it verbatim.  I think of this like the "Ikea" of database-driven output.

Of course if you ever do change data in a dimension table, you'd want to invalidate the cached HTML, or even better re-generate it and store a new version of the HTML in memcached.

Regarding doing all the lookups, I'll point out that there's no requirement to use pseudokeys in a fact table.  You can use the natural values, and make them reference the primary key of the dimension table, which also can be a natural key instead of a pseudokey.  It might take a bit more space in some cases, but it eliminates the lookups.  Of course it may make sense to continue using pseudokeys for dimensions that are long varchars.

Comment: Bill - I'd never heard of that before, but I'm a newbie. Sounds interesting and right in line with what I'm looking for. You're right, my dimensional tables don't change very often, if at all. They're full of static values that then pulled into the fact table. Also, your analogy regarding ikea really made your answer make sense to me. Do you have a link to an example of this? Is that asking too much?

Comment: Here's an article showing what I'm talking about with a Python application, but the same technique is used widely by PHP and Ruby developers:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by " a query to each individual lookup". Do you mean a way to save your entire table in your php script? Or do you mean a way to cache on the mysql server to eliminate process resources on the database node?

MySQL includes a built in Caching system that eliminates a lot of server cycles for similar queries. You can find more here-> [MySQL Caching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

As far as your database structure, you're going to have to provide a little bit more detail about your schema (What your database is meant to do) if you would like some suggestions. It's hard to know what kind of structure works and is effective without knowing what it's supposed to do. (Are there multiple notes per employee, what are costs? Are they per employee? etc)

Comment: Nope, I'm not talking about caching. I'm talking about building a table that has the lookups done already. When you look at the fact table, it's mainly just numbers in each column.

Most of those numbers represent the primary key of another table. So in order to present data to the user, where the data is meaningful, I have to lookup that key on the other table, and grab the column that represents the human readable data. Then continue to do that for each lookup, which is why I said "a query for each individual lookup".